# Add openssl c langage library on windows

Tags: c, email, ssl, openssl

I'm producing my 1st projet in c. I want to build a mail client.
I used the socket to do it.

But have some trouble with that methode. I can't send a mail with a gmail smtp server because of an encoding protocol.
So after some research, i understood that i haven't lot's of choice. I have to use the openssl library.

And that's the problem. I understood how to use that library (I hope, you can judge it with my code attached) but i never understand how to add the library.

On stackoverflow i find solutions for linux and android so i create a new post.

So that's my question:
What should I do with the zip file that i download from [openssl official website](https://www.openssl.org/source/)?. And even which zip file do I need to download ?

```
SOCKET connexion(char* server_name,unsigned short port)
{
    char buf[1024]={0};
    int res_l= 0;
    int nbrecv;
    struct sockaddr_in   serverSockAddr;                                               
    struct hostent     * serverHostEnt;                                                                 
    SOCKET to_server_socket = 0;
    memset(&serverSockAddr,0, sizeof(serverSockAddr) );                             
    serverHostEnt = gethostbyname( server_name );                                     
    if ( serverHostEnt == NULL )
    {
        res_l = h_errno;
        return (SOCKET)-1;
    }
    memcpy(&serverSockAddr.sin_addr,serverHostEnt->h_addr, serverHostEnt->h_length );   
        serverSockAddr.sin_port = htons( port );                                    
        serverSockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                                        

    to_server_socket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );                               

    if( connect( to_server_socket, ( struct sockaddr * ) &serverSockAddr,sizeof( serverSockAddr ) ) < 0 ) return (SOCKET)-3;
        while( !buf[0] ) nbrecv = recv( to_server_socket, buf, 1024, 0 );
        printf("Welcome message : %s\n",buf);                                                                                                               
        return to_server_socket;
}

void SendAndReceiveSSL(SSL * ssl, char * messagesend, int n){
{   
    char bufreceive[1024];                                                                  
    int size,retVal,nbrecv;                                                           
    size  = (int)strlen( messagesend );                                                
    retVal = SSL_write( ssl, messagesend, size);                                                                      
    printf("Envoye : %s\n",messagesend)   ;
    memset(bufreceive,0,1024);                                                                                                       
    if (n!=1)  //n=0 if i don't want an answer of the server.
    {
        while(!bufreceive[0]) nbrecv = SSL_read( ssl, bufreceive,1024);                                                                          
        printf("Recu : %s\n",bufreceive);                                                      
    }    
}

int mail_ssl(SOCKET sock, SSL ssl, const char* from,const char* to,const char* body)
{
#define SIZEMAX 1000

    char buffer[SIZEMAX]; int n=0;              
    SendAndReceive(sock, "EHLO localhost\r\n",n);       //no ssl for the 2 1st sentences//EHLO localhose ... wait 250
    SendAndReceive(sock, "STARTTLS\r\n,n)

    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, "EHLO localhost\r\n",n);     //sll for the next
    sprintf(buffer,"MAIL FROM: <%s>\r\n",from); 
    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, buffer,n);                           //MAIL FROM:<******> wait 250
    sprintf(buffer,"RCPT TO: <%s>\r\n",to);      
    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, buffer,n);                           //RCPT TO:<******> wait 250
    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, "DATA\r\n",n);                           //DATA wait 340
    sprintf(buffer, "Subject: %s\r\n",body); n=1;   
    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, buffer,n);    n=0;                       //Subject : subject \r\n body\r\n  ///// DON'T WAIT
    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, ".\r\n",n);                          //.\r\n                   wait 250
    SendAndReceiveSSL(ssl, "QUIT\r\n",n);
    return 0;
}

SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{
    SSL_METHOD *method;
        SSL_CTX *ctx;

        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  // Load cryptos, et.al.
        SSL_load_error_strings();   // Bring in and register error messages 
        method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  // Create new client-method instance 
        ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   // Create new context 
        if ( ctx == NULL )
     {
             ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
             abort();
        }
     return ctx;
}

void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); // get the server's certificate
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       // free the malloc'ed string 
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       // free the malloc'ed string 
            X509_free(cert);     // free the malloc'ed certificate copy 
    }
        else printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}

int authSSL(SOCKET sock, const char* from,const char* to,const char* body)
{   
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    SSL *ssl;

    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitCTX();
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);     
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )    
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else
    {  
            printf("Connected with %s encryption\n", SSL_get_cipher(ssl));
        ShowCerts(ssl);         
            SSL_write(ssl, msg, strlen(msg));    

        mail_ssl(sock, ssl, from, to, body); //In this function i collect
//all the informations to create the mail and i use all the function above
        SSL_free(ssl);
        }
    close(server);         // close socket 
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        // release context 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why not to use windows built in TLS APIs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/secure-winsock-programming https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/using-secure-socket-extensions

Comment: I never see that before. thanks you. It will be so much easier because all my programm already depending on winsock2.h.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [VCPKG package manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg), it will download and configure your envirument if you are using Visual Studio

Comment: So  i have to create by myself a library from the zip folder ?

Comment: No, VCPKG has openssl already in their repository https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/openssl